# Selecting all the rows in Excel based on whether the cells of a particular column are empty

Tags: excel, excel-2016

I want to select all the rows with the condition being that the rows must be those for which the cells of a particular column are blank. For example, if there are a total of 10 rows. 5 cells in column 3 are empty. How do I select those 5 rows for which cells in column 3 are empty?

Comment: It might be useful for us to know what you are trying to accomplish once those rows are selected

Comment: I want to move those rows to another excel file. I am actually building a regression model and those blank cells are the ones for which the predictions are to be made. Once I have got the rows with those blank cells selected, I'll move them to another file and predict those values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SpecialCells for this.

For example this will select all row where the cell in C1:C10 is empty:

```
Range("C1:C10").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Select
```

Note `SpecialCells` will throw an error if there are no blanks in the specified range, so you will have to trap that or test for it first.